# ground object collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a 2d game using pygame,how do i make the ground collide with the player

here is my game code, I am new to pygame and python

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__() 
    self.surf = pygame.image.load('img/PlayerIdle1.png')
    self.surf = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.surf,(44,44))
    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (10, 420))
    
    self.pos = vec((10, 360))
    self.vel = vec(0,0)
    self.acc = vec(0,0)
def gravity(self):
    self.acc = vec(0,0.5)

    self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

    self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
```

this update method for collision is not working

```
def update(self):
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(p1 ,Gro_und, False)
    if p1.vel.y > 0:        
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = 0
            self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            print('got hit')

     
      
def render(self):
      
      screen.blit(self.surf, self.rect)
      screen.blit(self.surf, self.rect)


class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.cimage = pygame.image.load('img/gnd.png')
        self.cimage = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.cimage,(800,200))
        self.rectCimg = self.cimage.get_rect()
        self.surf = self.cimage
        self.rect = self.rectCimg

        self.cY1 = 400
        self.cX1 = 0

        self.cY2 = 400
        self.cX2 = self.rectCimg.width

        self.scroll_speed = 20
     
  def update(self):


    self.cX1 -= self.scroll_speed
    self.cX2 -= self.scroll_speed
    if self.cX1 <= -self.rectCimg.width:
        self.cX1 = self.rectCimg.width
    if self.cX2 <= -self.rectCimg.width:
        self.cX2 = self.rectCimg.width
         
  def render(self):
     screen.blit(self.cimage, (self.cX1, self.cY1))
     screen.blit(self.cimage, (self.cX2, self.cY2))
     
  def gravity(self):
      pass

p1 = Player()         
back_ground = Background()
Gro_und = Ground()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

all_sprites.add(p1)
all_sprites.add(Gro_und)

run = True
while run:
  clock.tick(fps)


#draw and scroll the ground
back_ground.update()
back_ground.render()
Gro_und.update()
Gro_und.render()


for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
for entity in all_sprites:
      entity.update()
      entity.render()
      
      entity.gravity()

      
        
pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I am getting ground object not iterable error while running the  update function in player class for collision
what should i do to to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the reason you're getting a `Ground object not iterable` error is because the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` function is supposed to receive the sprite you want to check for collision with (in your case, `p1`), but the second parameter should be an instance of `pygame.sprite.Group`, which is iterable (unlike a normal sprite, which your `Ground` object is based upon.

I see that you have already made a sprite group, `all_sprites`, but you should create another one for just the ground (for example, `ground_sprites`), and then change the function call in your `update` function to be like so:

```
def update(self):
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(p1 ,ground_sprites, False)
    if p1.vel.y > 0:        
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = 0
            self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            print('got hit')
```